# Groupby on relation laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model

Hey i have three table like this

```
--table plan--
id
name
....

----table letter---
id
plan_id
....

---table person----
id
plan_id
name
.....
```

Model i have :

```
---Model plan---
class plan extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'plan';
    public function letter(){
       return $this->hasOne('App\letter');
    }
    public function person(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\person');
    }
}
--Model person--
class person extends Model
{
    public function plan(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\plan');
    }
}

--Model letter--
class letter extends Model
{
    public function plan(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\plan');
    }
}
```

And in controller i write code like this :

```
$letter = letter::find($id) // $id from url parameter and it's work
return view('letter',['letter' => $letter]);
```

Nah in view i wanna acces person name from letter model as distinct , so i write code like this

```
{{ @foreach ($letter->plan()->person()->groupBy('name')->get) as $person }}
```

but it return error like this :
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::person()

Where is my mistake(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `$letter->plan()` and `$letter->plan`. If you call it like a method, Laravel will return the Query Builder. If you call it like an attribute Laravel will return the model from that relation.

So you're trying to call your model on the Query Builder, which is a method that doesn't exists and creates the error. This will fix your problem:

`$letter->plan->person()->groupBy('name')->get()`

In your controller you can do:

```
$letter = letter::find($id) // $id from url parameter and it's work
$persons = $letter->plan->person()->groupBy('name')->get();

return view('letter', compact('letter', 'persons'));
```

And in your view:

```
@foreach($persons as $person)
```

Comment: In addition it's better to eager load plan and person `$letter = letter::with('plan.person')->find($id)` + you mean `return view('letter',['persons' => $persons]);`

Comment: Allright this problem is fixed, but there show another problem : Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'mydb.person.id' isn't in GROUP BY

Comment: nah everything work fine now, just misconfigured , thankss